# Python | Не работает приведение типа

Tags: python, numpy

Пытаюсь произвести приведение типа, но оно не работает.

```
print(type(res))
```

> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

```
 print(type(res[0][0]))
```

> <class 'numpy.complex128'>

```
res[0][0] = int(res[0][0].real) - пытаюсь привести тип
print(type(res[0][0]))
```

> <class 'numpy.complex128'>  - тип не изменился, почему?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

метод `.real` работает с массивом, а не с элементом массива numpy. поэтому в вашем случае корректно было сделать так:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=np.complex_)
print(type(a))
print(type(a[0][0]))
a = a.real.astype(int)
print(type(a[0][0]))
```

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.complex128'>
<class 'numpy.int32'>
```

массивы numpy не поддерживают множественные типы, все элементы должны быть одного типа, и всегда имплицитно приводятся к наиболее "сложному" из имеющихся, если иное не было задано явно.